# Use of general-purpose registers in Linux/x86

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu-registers

This is a general question (e.g. on Linux and x86):

Is it true that without calling syscall, a regular C program will not (implicitly) use any of general-purpose registers?

Comment: what is C program? do you mean binary with machine codes which is created from C source?

Comment: No, it is not true, if you mean registers like eax,ebx... These are used all the time.  Just look at an assembly output of any program for proof of this.

Comment: Any library function can use them, not just syscalls.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I guess that qualifies as *explicit* use.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess.  This is such a straight forward question though, that I truly wonder if I am missing the subtle point of what implicit would be.

Comment: It is not true, beside `syscall` we can load shared libraries (via `dlopen` or our own functions) and call their functions, which can change some registers which are not affected by main application, so we can call them as implicit change

Comment: @MichaelDorgan @BenVougt By implicit, I mean if in C program, it does not invoke `__asm__` that explicitly access `%%eax`, then anything qualifies as implicit access. If gcc compiles C program to assembly full of `%%eax`, then that answers my question...

Comment: Check what ABI means and how it applies to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d", argc);
}
```

Produces this assembly:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 10
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    %edi, %ecx
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "%d"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Which clearly uses the general purpose registers `eax`, `ecx`, and `esi`. Additionally, note that there are no system calls in this code, just a function call to libc's `_printf`.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question, although inside `glib`'s `_printf`, I believe there is a syscall (but that is irrelevant...).